# EXCEL FORMULA - Conditional format Date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, date

I am trying to work out a formula for the below specific Critia.

If cell is blank, colour in yellow if date is 2 days away, colour in red if date has 1 day over.

I am trying to build a traffic light system to alert when a follow date is approaching (Yellow) and when it had surpassed (RED)

Comment: Have you tried conditional formatting? More specificity and what you have tried would help us help you.

Comment: As  asked conditional formatting might be an easy solution for you.  I'm going to show a possibility in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested the screen cap below might give you some ideas
[image]